# PhoneGap and Retina display

Tags: iphone, cordova, retina-display

I'm creating an app for iPhone using phoneGap, but I'm sure it is not working using retina display, instead of that, it is using the old iPhone3 resolution.

Is there any way to have 2 versions for iPhone when developing using phoneGap? this is, one version using retina and another version with worst resolution for the older devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to use either CSS media queries or JavaScript.

http://troymcilvena.com/post/998277515/jquery-retina is a jQuery plugin that'll automatically handle @2x images.

In CSS, you'd need to use a media query targeting `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2` that replaces background images with their higher-resolution versions (and sets `background-size`).

Comment: You'd use the CSS media query for that. `@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { .ui-page { background: transparent url(path/to/2x.jpg); background-size: Xpx Ypx; } }` This changes the element for devices with a retina display's resolution only.

Answer (score 12):

[Retina.js](http://retinajs.com/) with less CSS it will solve your problem.

On the other hand, for problems with Phonegap (e.g.: you don’t see the page like it should, instead you see everything zoomed in) after using the following code in your app:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-
scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5" />
```

Add this into your Cordova.plist:

```
EnableViewportScale : YES
```

Comment: Enabling user-zoom in a phonegap or any other application is not a very smart move, in fact no app so far seems to allow that.

Comment: This does not work for me. When I do it, only the content of the page is scaled, not the actual UI elements used in the application, e.g. the status bar, which remains at an awkward size