# Phonegap screen gets cut off on Retina iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, css, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

[image]I have a Phonegap App which uses jQueryMobile 1.3.2 and Phonegap 3.1 (with the status bar plugin).
Everything works fine but the **iPad** Retina simulator (iOS 7) shows my screen cut off at the right hand side of the screen (**iPhone** Retina is fine, as are all Android layouts).

I'm using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" >
```

...and tried with both **EnableViewportScale true/false** - whereas it has no effect besides the Retina 64bit - where a *true* will completely distort the view (I only see a green/white block), and also:

```
html, body { width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

in my html pages. I have read through a few issues that iOS will return a different resolution value when "being retina", but never found anything in regards to fixing this related to phonegap.

The strange thing is, when I put set e.g. width=400 in the viewport meta tag, nothing changes... again, independent from the EnableViewportScale setting.

Thanks in advance for any clues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was the StatusBar plugin I used, which caused the weird layout. After removing it, the layout was fine again.

As to the status bar - I don't really need to control it during the app so I did the following:
Open the plist file (Resources/{ProjectName}-Info.plist) and add the key "View controller-based status bar appearance",  set it to "NO". Also create the key / make sure that "Status bar is initially hidden" is set to "YES".

Comment: I can confirm, it is a status bar plugin bug: https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />`

Comment: Try Providing Width:100% in CSS Styles.

Comment: Does this help ?! I guess It Should !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612330/phonegap-and-retina-display

Comment: As far as I can see this is only to exchange pictures depending on the resolution - but I have tried the viewport settings before without effect - thanks.